# Apply search patterns in Where method?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do the reverse of the `Select` method: to project bunch of items based on their `Id`, 
I'm thinking of `Where` so I would make something like this:

```
db.Books.Where(b => b.Id==1 || b.Id==3 || b.Id==5)
```

but if I have a long list of Id, or if I want to search by `Title` , it will be very painful code,
so is there a way to retrieve a list of items based on a group of values (like SQL: `WHERE id IN..`)

Comment: What the answers say: `.Where(b => new[] { 1, 3, 5, }.Contains(b.Id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' wrote an extension method, and it works great as I wanted, with any type and any member:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> In<TSource, TMember>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TMember> identifier, params TMember[] values) =>
 source.Where(m => values.Contains(identifier(m)));
```

You can call it like this:

```
var myBooks = Books.In(b => b.Id, 1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 22);
```

For my future needs, I uploaded it to NuGet

> Install-Package Mshwf.NiceLinq

Comment: That linq doesn't really look right. That's saying select all books where 'book is' its current id, 1, 3, 5, 8, 11, or 22. Not if the id is one of those values.

Comment: Is there a difference? the two approaches select the books that have these Id 's, right? except mine is more readable and easier

Comment: If you looked at it carefully you'll see they are the same, except I used generics to make it reusable

Comment: Yes, they are 'technically' the same. But imagine if someone doesn't know the definition of your method. Every single argument is an int. It just looks like the method is a single parameter of params int[]. It looks like you're selecting all current books AND books that have an '(id, probably)' 1,3,5,8,11,22. Not that you're matching the Id to values after it. That's not readable at all. EJoshuaS 's answer is much more readable. Declaring the in list on id in the first place just makes more sense as that's how the sql looks.

Comment: The package contains XML comments that makes it easy enough for a novice to understand that `params[] int` means he can pass the array values without having to make it explicitly, I wouldn't accept my answer here without being sure it fits me best (I answered some of my questions without accepting it, it's not a thing to me) and really this what I was looking for exactly when I asked the question, EJoshuaS 's answer shed a light on the importance of `Func` delegate to achieve this. If you think it's not readable or bad, then OK, it's your opinion

Answer (score 7):

```
string[] bookNames = { "BookName1", "BookName2" };

db.Books.Where(b => bookNames.Contains(b.Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions listed above all work - Dispersia's LINQ query's really nice actually.

One more possibility to keep in mind for what it's worth: you can always write your own LINQ-like extension methods. Here are a couple I put together for what they're worth. (I don't claim that these are actually better than the other solutions or that you'd necessarily want to use them instead - they're just something to keep in mind for reference in case you want to do something similar in the future).

Note that the compiler'll even allow you to add them to the System.Linq namespace if you want, but you could definitely argue about whether that's a good practice or not.

```
namespace System.Linq
{
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    // This one's more or less like "Contains" except for the "params" part
    // Example: book.Id.In(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    public static bool In<T>(this T item, params T[] list)
    {
        foreach (T args in list)
        {
            if (args.Equals(item))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Same idea as above except using an equality tester
    // Example: listBooks.Where(book => book.In((bk, id) => bk.Id == id, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    public static bool In<T, U>(this T item, Func<T, U, bool> equalitytester, params U[] list)
    {
        foreach (U arg in list)
        {
            if (equalitytester(item, arg))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    // See if any item in the first list is also in the second list
    public static bool In<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, U, bool> equalityTester, params U[] argList)
    {
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            foreach (U arg in argList)
            {
                if (equalityTester(item, arg))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `List<integer>` or an array of integers. Add values to it. AND USE `Contains` method

```
Where(b => lst.Contains(b))
```